# Передать анонимную функцию из Delphi в C++

Tags: c++, delphi, lambda

Здравствуйте, как можно передать анонимную функцию из Delphi в C++?
Delphi:

```
CallDelphiFunc(procedure
begin
  WriteLn('Called');
end);
```

C++:

```
void CallDelphiFunc(???) {
  ???
}
```

Comment: При чем здесь ее анонимность?

Comment: При том что ее не надо обьявлять с именем в Delphi, а она должна быть динамическая.

Comment: Опишите задачу подробнее, а то щас ощущение, что вы спрашиваете как лучше держать микроскоп для выкапывания ямы.

Answer (score 1):

Из Delphi в С++ (и обратно) можно что-то передать только через Си [ABI](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81_%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9) (не С++, а именно Си). А в Си нету понятия анонимной функции, так что из Delphi в С++ вы её передать не можете.

В Си, в качестве аргумента функции, можно передавать указатель на другую функцию и это та самая возможность, которая может помочь вам решить задачу.